# How should questions not written in English be handled?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just saw a question asked in what appears to me to be Italian. I can't answer it without running it through a translation program.

How should a question like this be handled?

Should it be closed?

Should we require that questions be posted in English? I don't want to seem elitist with the spoken/written language. I do want to be able to answer the question.

Comment: Should we add something to the Help Center that says questions should be in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be closed.  This is an English site (btw, you can try to figure out what it is and get the language detection with http://translate.google.com using the 'detect language').  Answers in not-english are:

- Not useful for people who don't speak the language searching
- If translated to english, may not be useful for the original poster

  - Furthermore, the OP is may be unable to give additional information
- We don't necessarily have the moderators who can handle issues that come up in non-english.
- We don't have the people able to read an off topic (or too broad or unclear) non-english question and decide if it is on topic or not.

While it may be something that someone can read, or send through google translate to get an essence of, it is ultimately something that the OP needs to put forth the effort into to write in the appropriate language.

We can go a long way to fixing spelling and grammar of someone who doesn't write English well - but it is necessary for it to start out and be conducted in English.

Asking a question in Stack Overflow (or P.SE) is no more appropriate than asking in English on [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

There are a set of area 51 proposals for Stack Overflow in XYZ:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian

---

MSE: [Non-English Q&A translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171034/non-english-qa-translations)

MSE: [Is English required on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)

MSE: [non-english-speakers tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-english-speakers)

SO Blog: [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)